# Excel/Polygon Challenge :how to create an extended bar Chart in Excel by using x and Y coordinates

Tags: excel-formula, excel-charts

Let's take.an.example.we have 5 category say

A-20%

B-40%

C-50%

D-70%

E-90%

Now I want to create something similar to the attached image by using X and Y coordinates

Note : I am not violating any bar chart best practices .I am just curious to know the process so that I can generate the x and Y coordinates dynamically. We need 7 points X and Y coordinates per category to get the extended horizontal bar chart.

Looking for some.answers..can anyone help?

Expected output: https://all-free-download.com/free-vector/download/horizontal-bar-chart-template_6826190.html

[image: Preview]

Can someone help me with this challenge ?

Comment: I think this is too complicated .I am.not getting any help/reply .Any Excel genius can help me with this

Comment: Any reply would be appreciated.#Excel #programming #ETL

Comment: You are probably trying to use a wrong software to achieve the above chart. Excel has its limitations when it comes to data visualization. Try PowerBI or google some other tools that is specialized in data visualization.

Comment: I think that make sense but let's take an example I am.usimg tableau but still I need to take 7 points to.draw such graph.Do you know any website which can help me getting the desired output